# How to make nginx ssl with port 8443

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to add ssl on 8443 in nginx *(For some reason I cannot use 443)*. The `.conf` file is as

```
server {
    listen 9081;
    server_name myserver.someserver.in;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    # include conf.d/gzip.conf;

    location / {
        root /home/some/path;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 8443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

But, after hitting myserver.someserver.in:9081, I'm getting error citing `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`. Am I missing something?

UPDATE - 
Content of included files are:
file -> self-signed.conf

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
```

file -> ssl-params.conf

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Comment: You should specify `ssl_ciphers` and `ssl_protocols`

Comment: what is in the config files that you are including in you SSL server block?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).